# for loop printing i in div incorrectly

Tags: javascript

```js
function generer() {

  var antall = Number(document.getElementById('antall').value);
  var drikke = document.getElementById('drikke').value;

  for (let i = antall; i >= 0; i--) {
    vers = i + ' bottles of ' + drikke + ' on the wall <br>' + i + ' bottles of ' + drikke + '<br> If one of those bottles should happen to fall <br><br>';
    console.log(vers);

  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = vers.repeat(antall);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>100-bottles</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="antall" placeholder="Antall vers"><br>
  <input type="text" id="drikke" placeholder="Type drikke"><br>
  <button id="knapp" onclick="generer()">Generer vers</button>
  <div id="output">
    <p>Vers kommer her:</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So the idea is to print out a number of verses, and a drink, and to then repeat that verse x(inputted) amount of times. My code does this, however, i have no clue as to why it outputs correctly in console, yet the number inputted always displays as 0 in the div I'm outputting it in. I tried making a while loop (not very skillful at that) yet to no avail. Also if helping, please mention WHY i am wrong/ it doesn't work.

Comment: @connexo that's not what the song sings about. http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/lyrics.html

Comment: You might also consider using type number for your input since as far as i understand it is about putting in an amount of iterations. `<input type="number" id="antall" placeholder="Antall vers">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the expected result in the console because you display `vers` for each iteration of the for-loop. While you are iterating in the for-loop, the value of `i` is decreasing, and a new value of `vers`, with `i` in it, is logged. Each console log shows the current value of `vers` as `i` decreases.

When you finally write to the DOM, you have completed all of your for-loop iterations. At this time, the value of `vers` has settled to its last value, and it begins with "0 bottles".

Your code then creates a new string in which the value of `vers`, beginning with "0 bottles", is repeated several times. You render this big string to the DOM. So you see "0 bottles" repeated over and over.

Comment: This and then just put `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML + vers` where you have your `console.log()` inside of the for loop.

Comment: Or as @Mark suggests in a different answer, accumulate the output into an array and then output the join of the array as a single string in one shot to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You keep overriding the variable `vers` and therefore it will only contain the vers generated by the last iteration of the for loop. After that you're repeating the text of the last iteration `antall` amount of times and displaying it.

You can do something like this, the value generated in each iteration of the for loop is added to an array, and later joined after which it's displayed in the element:

```js
function generer() {

  var antall = Number(document.getElementById('antall').value);
  var drikke = document.getElementById('drikke').value;
  var verses = [];

  for (let i = antall; i >= 0; i--) {
    vers = i + ' bottles of ' + drikke + ' on the wall <br>' + i + ' bottles of ' + drikke + '<br> If one of those bottles should happen to fall <br><br>';
    console.log(vers);
    verses.push(vers);
  }
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = verses.join("");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>100-bottles</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="antall" placeholder="Antall vers"><br>
  <input type="text" id="drikke" placeholder="Type drikke"><br>
  <button id="knapp" onclick="generer()">Generer vers</button>
  <div id="output">
    <p>Vers kommer her:</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted because it offers a solution, which probably helps the OP to understand what went wrong better.